# Google map api not showing map after app being deployed to heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var cors = require('cors');

//setup view engine
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

//setup routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

//bodyParser middleware
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//public files serving
app.use(express.static('public'));


//setup port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log('Server up on 3000');
});
```

view that shows the map

```
 <style type="text/css">

    #map {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
    }


    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }


    #panel {
      height: 100%;
      width: null;
      background-color: white;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: all .2s ease-out;
    }

    .open {
      width: 250px;
    }

    /* Styling for place details */
    .hero {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      max-height: 166px;
      display: block;
    }

    .place,
    p {
      font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;
      padding-left: 18px;
      padding-right: 18px;
    }

    .details {
      color: darkslategrey;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: cadetblue;
    }

</style>
  <div id="panel"></div> 
<div id="map">




    let pos = { lat: 31.669746, lng: -7.973328 };
    let map;
    let bounds;
    let infoWindow;
    let currentInfoWindow;
    let service;
    let infoPane;
    function initMap() {
      // Initialize variables
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;

      infoPane = document.getElementById('panel');

      // Try HTML5 geolocation
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: pos,
            zoom: 15
          });
          bounds.extend(pos);

          infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
          infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
          infoWindow.open(map);
          map.setCenter(pos);

          // Call Places Nearby Search on user's location
          getNearbyPlaces(pos);
        }, () => {
          // Browser supports geolocation, but user has denied permission
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow);
        });
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow);
      }
    }

    // Handle a geolocation error
    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow) {
      // Set default location to Sydney, Australia

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: pos,
        zoom: 15
      });

      // Display an InfoWindow at the map center
      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Geolocation permissions denied. Using default location.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
      currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;

      // Call Places Nearby Search on the default location
      getNearbyPlaces(pos);
    }

    // Perform a Places Nearby Search Request
    function getNearbyPlaces(position) {
      let request = {
        location: position,
        rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
        keyword: 'pharmacy'
      };

      service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.nearbySearch(request, nearbyCallback);
    }

    // Handle the results (up to 20) of the Nearby Search
    function nearbyCallback(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        createMarkers(results);
      }
    }

    // Set markers at the location of each place result
    function createMarkers(places) {
      places.forEach(place => {
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: place.geometry.location,
          map: map,
          title: place.name
        });


        // Add click listener to each marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
          let request = {
            placeId: place.place_id,
            fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'geometry', 'rating',
              'website', 'photos']
          };

          * the search response, we will hit API rate limits. */
          service.getDetails(request, (placeResult, status) => {
            showDetails(placeResult, marker, status)
          });
        });

        // Adjust the map bounds to include the location of this marker
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      });
      /* Once all the markers have been placed, adjust the bounds of the map to
       * show all the markers within the visible area. */
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }


    function showDetails(placeResult, marker, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        let placeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        let rating = "None";
        if (placeResult.rating) rating = placeResult.rating;
        placeInfowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + placeResult.name +
          '</strong><br>' + 'Rating: ' + rating + '</div>');
        placeInfowindow.open(marker.map, marker);
        currentInfoWindow.close();
        currentInfoWindow = placeInfowindow;
        showPanel(placeResult);
      } else {
        console.log('showDetails failed: ' + status);
      }
    }


    function showPanel(placeResult) {
      // If infoPane is already open, close it
      if (infoPane.classList.contains("open")) {
        infoPane.classList.remove("open");
      }

      // Clear the previous details
      while (infoPane.lastChild) {
        infoPane.removeChild(infoPane.lastChild);
      }


      // Add the primary photo, if there is one
      if (placeResult.photos) {
        let firstPhoto = placeResult.photos[0];
        let photo = document.createElement('img');
        photo.classList.add('hero');
        photo.src = firstPhoto.getUrl();
        infoPane.appendChild(photo);
      }

      // Add place details with text formatting
      let name = document.createElement('h1');
      name.classList.add('place');
      name.textContent = placeResult.name;
      infoPane.appendChild(name);
      if (placeResult.rating) {
        let rating = document.createElement('p');
        rating.classList.add('details');
        rating.textContent = `Rating: ${placeResult.rating} \u272e`;
        infoPane.appendChild(rating);
      }
      let address = document.createElement('p');
      address.classList.add('details');
      address.textContent = placeResult.formatted_address;
      infoPane.appendChild(address);
      if (placeResult.website) {
        let websitePara = document.createElement('p');
        let websiteLink = document.createElement('a');
        let websiteUrl = document.createTextNode(placeResult.website);
        websiteLink.appendChild(websiteUrl);
        websiteLink.title = placeResult.website;
        websiteLink.href = placeResult.website;
        websitePara.appendChild(websiteLink);
        infoPane.appendChild(websitePara);
      }

      // Open the infoPane
      infoPane.classList.add("open");
    }



  </script>
```

Im loading im loading the google map javascrip api in main.hbs but it all works fine locally not on heroku when anyone go to the web link.

I have also set some api restirections i.e 0.0.0.0/0 maybe the purpose for this was to get and show the map when somone come to web app with any ip

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Google Maps API keys are right.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that i had to load the map script in the same page and i was loding it on other and it was loading first so causing many errors its working now just includeded the script on same file in the end of map function.